# Javascript: how to draw same polygon in many positions?

Tags: javascript, graphics, polygon

I am trying to create a simple game simulation in which user will select a plane and move it around.
I am able to draw a single plane and added 4 buttons to move it around.
But, I am not sure how to create 6 exact same planes in random locations and draw them.
Also, user must be able to select one of the planes and move it around.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvtjzLhr/

HTML Code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="Left">Left</button>
<button id="Up">Up</button>
<button id="Down">Down</button>
<button id="Right">Right</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var poly=[ 20,0, 40,0, 50,15, 100,10, 130,30, 100,50, 50,45, 40,60, 20,60, 30,45, 20,40, 10,40, 0,45, 0,15, 10,20, 20,20, 30,15];

    var spaceship1 = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        speed: 50,
        altitude: 360,
        id: 68,
        direction: 150
    }

    document.getElementById("Up").addEventListener("click", function(){
        spaceship1.y -= 30;
    });
    document.getElementById("Down").addEventListener("click", function(){
        spaceship1.y += 30;
    });
    document.getElementById("Left").addEventListener("click", function(){
        spaceship1.x -= 30;
    });
    document.getElementById("Right").addEventListener("click", function(){
        spaceship1.x += 30;
    });

    function renderSpaceship(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //ctx.fillStyle = '#D3D3D3';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(poly[0]+spaceship1.x, poly[1]+spaceship1.y);
        for( item=2 ; item < poly.length-1 ; item+=2 ){ctx.lineTo( poly[item]+spaceship1.x , poly[item+1]+spaceship1.y )}
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font="17px Georgia";

        ctx.fillText("ID: "+spaceship1.id, spaceship1.x, 120+spaceship1.y);
        ctx.fillText("Altitude: "+spaceship1.altitude, spaceship1.x, 105+spaceship1.y);
        ctx.fillText("Speed: "+spaceship1.speed, spaceship1.x, 90+spaceship1.y);
        ctx.fillText("Direction: "+spaceship1.direction, spaceship1.x, 75+spaceship1.y);
    }

    function renderAll(){

        renderSpaceship();
    }

    setInterval(renderAll, 10);
```

It should look something like this:
[image]

Ignore the background. Blue color is for the selected plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to stay away from naming ships and storing them in variables like `Spaceship1`, this leads to a lot of repeated code once you need to start implementing many ships.

To avoid duplicating code, create an array to hold each ship in your game.  Your draw function should loop through each element of the ship array and draw it.

You can create a variable called `selectedShip` and update that ships position whenever the up/down/right/left buttons are clicked.  To 'select' a different ship just listen for clicks on your canvas and detect a click on a ship.  If a ship is clicked, update your `selectedShip` variable to the one that was clicked on.

Some snippets of edits to your fiddle:

Loop through every ship when drawing

```
function renderSpaceships() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
    var ship = ships[i];      
    ...
  }
```

Add a helper function to create ships in one line

```
function addShip(x, y, id){
  ships.push({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    speed: 50,
    altitude: 320,
    id: id,
    direction: 150
  });
}

addShip(getRand(1, 400), getRand(1, 400), 68);
```

I haven't added any click listeners for your ships, you will need to get coordinates of the click and check if any ship in your array overlaps with the point clicked on.  Then update `selectedShip`.

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvtjzLhr/2/)

This should get you pointed in a good direction to keep adding functionality while keeping things neat.  Good luck!